# Ansible - condition on with_sequence loop with variable end that could be less than start

Tags: loops, ansible

I am having issue with an ansible with_sequence loop where the end is a variable that could be zero. 
I am looking for a way to skip the loop so I don't get the error "to count backwards make stride negative".

Simplified sample :

```
- name : Register zero as var

  # The real command is something like "script | filter | wc -l"
  shell: echo 0
  register: countvar

  # I want this loop to run only when countvar is > 0

- name: Do smthg with countvar
  command: echo "{{ item }}"
  with_sequence: start=1 end={{countvar.stdout|int}}
  when: countvar.stdout|int >= 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `when` condition is executed at each iteration on the loop, it cannot be used as a way to not enter the loop, just to skip an iteration.

If you are using ansible>=2.0, you can use a [`block`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) around your task with your condition:

```
- block:
    - name: Do smthg with countvar
      command: echo "{{ item }}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end={{countvar.stdout|int}}
  when: countvar.stdout|int > 0
```

But, as you said, **it doesn't work** (I didn't test my answer) because the `end` value is evaluated anyway and the task fail. A solution is to protect it and then you can skip the `block` part:

```
  - name: Do smthg with countvar
    command: echo "{{ item }}"
    with_sequence: start=1 end={{countvar.stdout|int if countvar.stdout|int > 0 else 1}}
    when: countvar.stdout|int > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it does not seem to solve the issue. The error is still present. Ansible 2.3.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you believe the block being evaluated even when the condition is not met to be a bug ?

Comment: No I think that the mechanisms of block just apply the properties ('when' in your case) to each task in the block.

Comment: The second code suggested added to this answer definitely works, and the behavior is very sensible. It's a little ugly to write, but it seems this is the best available option.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was slightly different; I wanted to start the loop with `index: 1`, but only if the ending index is > 0. Meaning I did not want to default the ending index to 1.

```
loop: "{{  query('sequence', 'start=1 end=' + countvar.stdout) if  countvar.stdout|int > 0 else [] }}"
```

Here, the ending index will remain the same if `countvar.stdout > 0` else supply empty list `[]` to the loop.